# std::set of RTYPE values in Rcpp

Tags: c++, rcpp

Say I would like to implement a function that counts the unique values, e.g.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using Rcpp::Vector;
using Rcpp::traits::is_na;
using Rcpp::IntegerVector;

template <int RTYPE>
IntegerVector nunique( const Vector<RTYPE>& x ) {
    std::set<typename Rcpp::traits::storage_type<RTYPE>::type> values;
    for ( int i = 0; i < x.length(); ++i ) {
      if ( !is_na<RTYPE>(x[i]) )
        values.insert(x[i]);
    }
    return IntegerVector::create(values.size());
}
```

However this won't compile and throws errors like:

```
error: call of overloaded 'insert(Rcpp::Vector<19>::const_Proxy)' is ambiguous
         values.insert(x[i]);
```

or

```
error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'const Rcomplex' and 'const Rcomplex')
       { return __x < __y; }
```

Is there any way to create a `std::set` of RTYPE objects? Alternatively, how could I use some kind of hashes of such objects to count the unique values?

Comment: what do you mean by writing <int RTYPE>? Is RTYPE a type or integer template parameter? What is Vector template?

Comment: well... with the error the problem is rather clear, isnt it? There is no natural ordering of points in a 2D plane, especially there is no natural way to define `operator<` for complex numbers, hence if you want to put them in a set you need to define such a ordering (and pass it as parameter to the set)

Comment: @tobi303 If you define the operator it throws a whole bunch of errors of the first type. Maybe you could post an answer with working code?

Answer (score 0):

We have a few examples at the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org) that show how to do dynamic run-time switching based on the run-time loading the SEXP type coming in here as a compile-time RTYPE.

The compiler can't know whether you call with an integer or numeric... yet the R-based back end you want to insert into needs a type.  I think you can do what you want with a [std::variant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) (C++17) or its [Boost version](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/variant.html).

Or just switch over atomic types.